# Save NavigationLink selection

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm building a desktop application that has a sidebar. It should behave like this:

1. The user is able to add and remove elements to a list that is displayed in the sidebar.
2. A selected list element needs to remain selected when restarting the application.
3. Upon adding a new element, the new element gets selected.

I'm having issues with achieving the 2. and 3. point.

This is my view:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct Sidebar: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(entity: Element.entity(),  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Element.title, ascending: false)])
    private var elements: FetchedResults<Element>
    
    @State var selectedElementId: NSManagedObjectID?

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            List(self.elements) { element in
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), tag: element.objectID, selection: self.$selectedElementId) {
                    Text(element.title!)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: addElement) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                
                Button(action: removeElement) {
                    Image(systemName: "minus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addElement() {
        let element = Element(context: viewContext)
        
        element.title = "My title"
      
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Unresolved error \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private func removeElement() {
        if self.$selectedElementId.wrappedValue == nil {
            return
        }
        
        let element = viewContext.object(with: self.$selectedElementId.wrappedValue!)
        
        viewContext.delete(element)
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Unresolved error \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

To achieve the 2. and 3. point, I tried this:

I'm using core data as my storage. My idea is to have an attribute `Element.selection` which would tell me what list item was last selected, but I don't know how to update the `$selectedElementId`. I tried this in `addElement` but it doesn't work as expected:

```
private func addElement() {
    let element = Element(context: viewContext)
            
    element.title = "My title"

    if self.$selectedElementId.wrappedValue != nil {
        let selectedElement = viewContext.object(with: self.$selectedElementId.wrappedValue!)
            
        selectedElement.entity.selected = false
    }
       
    self.$selectedElementId.wrappedValue = element.objectID

    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("Unresolved error \(error)")
    }
}
```

This has two issues:

1. I want to set the new element as the selected element, therefore I need to update `self.$selectedElementId` to `element.objectId`. How can I do that? `wrappedValue` seems to be read-only.
2. I need to set `Element.selection` to `false` for the currently selected attribute. I've fetched the element in `selectedElement`, but I don't know how to update any values as it's of type `NSManagedObject`, not `Element`.

I'm new to Swift. Please let me know if there are also other elements of my approach that are wrong or could be done better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to fix a few things to get this working.

First, your `addElement()` method isn’t working because you need to set your state var directly to trigger an update, i.e.:

```swift
// Do this
self.selectedElementId = element.objectID

// Not this
self.$selectedElementId.wrappedValue = element.objectID
```

Second, you’re trying to store *application state* — the user’s selection — in your database. In general, databases are for user *data* and app state should be stored elsewhere. On Mac and iOS that place is usually `UserDefaults` (aka `@AppStorage` in SwiftUI), but for what you want SwiftUI has a specific solution: `@SceneStorage`. Anything you put in `SceneStorage` is saved per-*scene*, which is perfect for your case because users can open multiple windows and have different selection in each window.

And better yet, SceneStorage is super simple, just add the property `@SceneStorage` with a unique key to whatever property should be saved:

```swift
@SceneStorage("com.appname.selected_element") var selectedElementId: NSManagedObjectID?
```

… oh except that won’t compile because `SceneStorage` only works for a few basic types like Int and String. If you add a string property `identifier` to `Element`, then you can use it everywhere instead of NSManagedObjectID:

```swift
struct Sidebar: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(entity: Element.entity(),  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Element.title, ascending: false)])
    private var elements: FetchedResults<Element>
    
    @SceneStorage("com.appname.selected_element") var selectedElementId: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            List(self.elements) { element in
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(),
                               tag: element.identifier!,
                               selection: self.$selectedElementId) {
                    Text(element.title!)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: addElement) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                
                Button(action: removeElement) {
                    Image(systemName: "minus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addElement() {
        let element = Element(context: viewContext)
        element.title = "My title"

        // set identifier to a random UUID
        element.identifier = UUID().uuidString
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Unresolved error \(error)")
        }

        // select our newly-added element
        self.selectedElementId = element.identifier
    }
    
    private func removeElement() {
        // TODO: fetch selected object with identifier == $selectedElementId
    }
}
```

One more thing that may help is setting the selection in your `List`, but this doesn’t seem to be required:

```swift
List(self.elements, id: \.identifier, selection:$selectedElementId) {
```

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks for the detailed answer, it's really helpful. For some reason, `SceneStorage` doesn't work for `selectedElementId`, but `AppStorage` does. Do you maybe know what could be causing the issue?

Comment: SceneStorage doesn’t work for `String?`? Iirc I got the exact code I shared working on my system (macos 11.2 b1, Xcode 12.3). Did you get an error or the selection simply didn’t restore? Did you try adding `selection:$selectedElementId` to your `List`?

Comment: I'm building a macOS application and the docs for `SceneStorage` say: "If the Scene is explictly destroyed (e.g. the switcher snapshot is destroyed on iPadOS or the window is closed on macOS), the data is also destroyed.". Therefore AppStorage seems to be better suited for my needs as I was closing a window. Thanks!

Comment: Added for clarity, for others who visit this Q&A... I use this technique described by @Adam in my Multiplatform app and it works perfectly for macOS (12.0) and iOS (15.0) targets using Xcode Version 13.3.1... There are complexities to `@SceneStorage` I'm yet to fully understand but it does plays well with other scenes and so may be the better choice in many situations. To clarify, if a user closes a window (macOS) then the user has intentionally destroyed the scene. So IMHO the question (for others) is about whether you're attempting to capture user data, or the state of the scene